# Can Wet and Forget be used in a basement?

Tags: basement, mold

Can Wet and Forget (or similar product) be used in an unfinished basement? This style of spray connects to a garden hose and mixes as it is sprayed on affected areas.

I am wondering if the additional moisture is just going to cause further mold problems if it's unable to dry as it would when used outdoors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. From their FAQ:

> Can I use Wet & Forget indoors?
>
> Wet & Forget is specially formulated for outdoor use and requires
>   exposure to the weather to work properly. For indoor use, we recommend
>   Wet & Forget Indoor Mold+Mildew Disinfectant Cleaner.

See:  [Wet and Forget FAQ](https://www.wetandforget.com/faq-wet-and-forget-concentrate.html)